# How to get a list of Customer credit cards in braintree

Tags: php, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using braintree payment gateway and i wanted to know how to fetch a paginated list of customer cards.

Currently i can get the details using

```
$result = \Braintree_Customer::find('id');
print_r($result->creditCards);
```

But is there a way to add limit to it.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, I suggest you [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

No, there isn't. Keep in mind a customer is meant to represent a specific person / account, so there shouldn't be a situation in which a single customer has a large number of cards.